# Rotate integer for maximum trailing binary zeros

Tags: c++, c++11, rotation, bit-manipulation

Given 16 bits of data, I need to (using C++11) find the rotation that maximises the number of trailing zeros.

e.g. (using 8 bits for clarity),

```
10110001 -> 11011000 so rot=1
10000011 -> 11100000 so rot=2
etc.
```

Obviously it's easy enough to 'brute force' it. But I suspect there is an elegant solution.

Comment: You're assume rotating right in your example.  Are left rotations allowed also?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: the rotation direction doesn't matter. rotation is, well, rotation, like.

Comment: For example, you can use the minus-1-and-xor trick to convert each bitpattern to a number that is a monotonically increasing function of the number of trailing zeros. Then just try each of the 16 possibilities.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad.

Comment: When is this homework assignment due?

Comment: You could do a search (for the longest part with 0) from the lowest bit to the highest, the start position of that part is the number of rotations necessary if the part is longer than the sum of leading and trailing zeros. Otherwise the lower of these numbers (of leading / trailing zeros) is the number of rotations. This runs in O(number of bits). Obviously this makes only sense of you have a lot (a lot) bits. With 16 ... you're better off with brute force.

Comment: One small correction: you'd need to use the minimum of he start position or the number of bits - that start position, to also take left shifting into account.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, poisoning a community resource with your sarcasm.. O jaded heart. This was a fun challenge I posted. Alf got it. And I've provided an answer below. Challenge your motivation!

Comment: This "community resource"'s purpose, last time I checked, wasn't to share various challenges and puzzles, but for genuine questions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, it is both a puzzle and a genuine question! I have answered it myself. If someone can improve, I'm interested. But that is not the issue. The issue is that irrespective of the question, sarcasm creates a bad smell, a bad atmosphere. It should have no place here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the 'elegant solution' idea I was considering: 
Suppose we are testing x = 1110 0000.
Subtracting 1 gives 11011 1111.
And x ^ (x-1) = 0011 0000.

i.e. We will always get a number of this form, depending on the number of trailing zeros.

The most trailing zeros will yield the biggest number.

So Pythonesque pseudocode might look like:

```
iWinner = [x ^ (x-1) where x=rot(X,i) for i in range(16)].indexWithMaxValue()
```

In C:

```
uint16_t x = 42;
uint16_t xWinner=0;
for(uint16_t i=0,yMax=0; i<16; i++) {
    x = x << 1 + x >> 15; // rotate 1 left
    uint16_t y = x ^ (x-1);
    if( y > yMax ) {
        yMax = y;
        xWinner = x;
    }
}
```

I can't see any way of leveraging C++ to clean it up further however.

Answer (score 1):

I think that everything is clear in the code. Shift Left by analogy. You can test on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

const int count_bits = 8;

int num_right_rotation(std::string number)
{
    int max = 0;
    int rotation = 0;
    std::bitset<count_bits> one (number);
    for(int i=0; i<count_bits; i++)
    {
        int max_temp = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<count_bits; j++)
        {
            if(!one[j]) max_temp++;
            else break;
        }

        if(max_temp > max)
        {
            max = max_temp;
            rotation = i;
        }
        one = (one>>1) | (one<<count_bits-1);
    }
    return rotation;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << num_right_rotation ("10110001") << std::endl;
    std::cout << num_right_rotation ("10000011") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function yields the left rotation distance (since you probably want to use std::rotate afterwards). Idea: Walk through the bits, when you stumble upon a 0, count the zeros from there. Use modulo to wrap around the end and continue counting:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int rotation(std::string bits)
{
  int max_pos = 0;
  int max_count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < bits.size();)
  {
    if (bits[i] == '0')
    {
      int count = 1;
      for (; bits[(i + count) % bits.size()] == '0' && count < bits.size(); 
             ++count);
      if (count > max_count)
      {
        max_pos = i;
        max_count = count;
      }
      i += count;
    }
    else
    {
      ++i;
    }
  }

  return (max_pos + max_count) % bits.size();
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << rotation ("10110001") << std::endl;
  std::cout << rotation ("10000011") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```